# Relaxed Delegate Conversion, and multiple method arguments

Tags: vb.net, delegates, overloading, implicit-conversion

I have this code:

```
Friend Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim t1 = New Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyTimerCallback)
    Dim t2 = New Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyTimerCallback, Nothing, 0, 1000)
End Sub

Private Sub MyTimerCallback()
    'do something
End Sub
```

There is a compiler error on the first arg in the second line in `Main`:

> Argument matching parameter 'callback' narrows to 'System.Threading.TimerCallback'

The `Threading.Timer` constructor overloads all take a `Threading.TimerCallback` as the first argument, which is a delegate that takes one `Object` argument.  I understand that the first line works due to [Relaxed Delegate Conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531336.aspx), but why is it not working for the second line in `Main` which uses another overload of that constructor with the same first argument?

Furthermore, this works as well:

```
Dim t3 = New Threading.Timer(New Threading.TimerCallback(AddressOf MyTimerCallback), Nothing, 0, 1000)
```

Why does that work and not `Dim t2 = New Threading.Timer(AddressOf MyTimerCallback, Nothing, 0, 1000)`?

Comment: Just a wild guess: the callback method of the second constructor must receive an  `Object` as a parameter.

Comment: @JoshPart -- Please see updated question.  The first constructor takes the same.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but the second constructor **specifically** receives as a parameter the object it will send to the callback, so it requires the callback to receive something. It doesn't know if that object is `Nothing`, or if actually `Nothing` means something to the callback.

Comment: You are missing the state argument in the `MyTimerCallback` sub. Even if you are don't plan on using it (you are passing in `Nothing`) you still need to declare it. `Private Sub MyTimerCallback(oState As Object)`

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo -- I know I'm missing the state argument (hence my whole thing about relaxed delegate conversion).  My question is about why this works in one overload and doesn't in another.

Comment: I see no compelling reason in the language spec (chapter 11.10.3) that forbids this.  So it must be a bug, you can file it at connect.microsoft.com.  Pretty cringeworthy feature however, the lambda that's needed to make this code run doesn't come for free.  Best to keep programming with Option Strict On for a while.

Comment: @HansPassant -- Thanks, I agree it's cringeworthy.

Comment: @HansPassant more of a "language feature" than a bug as C# doesn't allow you to do this in any of the 3 ways